# How can I exterminate my private optical disks easily?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

I have been storing some *private data* (mostly documents) in CDs and DVDs for a long time. Now they have become obsolete and unnecessary, so I am going to throw them all to garbage can.

What I want to do is to make them unreadable by an easy method. I don't want to scrape them one by one, or to burn them all. I don't need to thoroughly exterminate the data as there are no any governmental secret files in them; I just want to make sure when somebody finds one in the garbage piles, he shouldn't be able to read the data by an optical disk drive. So I need an easy and non-time-consuming method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think cutting them in half using a pair of scissors would be your quickest fix. You could ask if someone you know has a paper/CD shredder which would also be a quick fix.

Comment: a lot of cross cutting paper shredders can easily cds and dvds.

Comment: Cutting from the edge to the center with scissors is adequate.

Answer (score 2):

You could snap them in half, but they might shatter so you'd need to beware of flying pieces - so it's not to be recommended. A well placed hammer blow would do the job just as well and you could wrap the discs in a bag to contain the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how this can be healthy but you could try to *cook* them in a microwave owen for some seconds.

Comment: Quite a light show that will give =P Not the safest bet/answer don't you think?

Comment: In seconds all the data will be unreadable, the question stated **quickly** (quicker than cut them one by one with a pair of scissors...), also I warned about the healthy drawback of such operation. Can't see the reason of -1.

Comment: Sorry cYrus, I didn't downvote, but I can see why the others did.

Answer (score 1):

Use this on both sides of the disc:

[image]